# Swift Protocol on a specific class?

Tags: swift

I am building a UIPresentationController subclass. UIPresentationController defines an default initializer like this:

```
init(presentedViewController: UIViewController , presentingViewController: UIViewController?)
```

Now, in order for this to work, I want my `presentedViewController` to conform to some protocol, say `MyRandomProtocol`.

How can I re-write my initializer such that it takes the first argument as both a UIViewController subclass, and one that specifically conforms to `MyRandomProtocol`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics.

```
init<T: UIViewController>(presentedViewController: T, ...) where T: MyRandomProtocol  {
    //initialization code
}
```

Comment: ended up with this: `    required init<T: UIViewController>(presented: T, where T: ScrollViewProvider, presenting: UIViewController) {
        super.init(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
    }`